# how to pass api key along with the post request

Tags: angular, http-post, httprequest

I'm using angular and have post request, I got unauthorize error which turned out.
I need to pass the api key as well, here is my post request:

```
SendToBackEnd(){         
    var x=new mymodel();
    x.settlementCurrency='EUR';
    x.customerReference='m455';
    x.paymentReference='65465465';
    this.http.post("address",x).subscribe(s=>{
    });
}
```

Could you please help me with that? no idea how I should pass the api key along with my request

Comment: Id say, either put it on the address or on x. `x.apiKey="mykey"` or `address?apikey=mykey`. That would depend on how your backend is expecting it and handling it. We cannot really tell without knowing the backend code.

Comment: @TheFool in the postman its inside of the header,and i still get 401 error

Comment: you get an error in postman? You have in an *Authorization* header like `Bearer mykey` ?

Comment: @TheFool in postman its working in angular error 401,in postman api key is in the header

Comment: What kind of header?

Comment: You need to set the header on your post request in the code, then. Look up angular documentation how to set headers when doing request and replicate what you have in postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is located address provide parameter for Auth to your end point

```
var address = 'https://adressToEndpoint.com/?apiKey=key 

  SendToBackEnd(){         
        var x=new mymodel();
        x.settlementCurrency='EUR';
        x.customerReference='m455';
        x.paymentReference='65465465';
        this.http.post("address",x).subscribe(s=>{
        });
      }
```

Comment: its inside of my header in the postman,im still getting error 401

Comment: Make sure that you provide key in correct order .

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I create a function for headers, so I can reuse it anywhere. You might want to put this function in a helper file to reuse it.

```
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('api-key', `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`);
  }


  SendToBackEnd(){
    const header = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(header);
     
    var x=new mymodel();
    x.settlementCurrency='EUR';
    x.customerReference='m455';
    x.paymentReference='65465465';
    this.http.post("address",x,
    {
      headers: header
     }).subscribe(s=>{
    });
  }
```

Please note that `api-key` should named the way your server expects it to be e.g apiKey.